# Android call Rest API in a loop

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm new to android, so have some questions regarding `api` calls.

Currently i use Retrofit to accomplish my api calls.

***Here is example of my api call with retrofit***

```
@POST("posts/new")
fun createPost(@Body post: Post, @Header("Authorization") token: String): Single<PostResult>
```

So, assume i have 10 posts and i need to call `createPost` 10 times (Yes, i know i can have `list` input on BE side, but ... ). Best way is to iterate over posts (`for/map`) and send them to the server.

But here is problem:
 - How do i can track that all calls are done?

In JS i can have something like `Promise.all` - could i do something
   similar in android?

I thought about counting the finished vs started requests, but i think it's bit ugly isn't?

Comment: Your question is broad. You could use RxJava to zip, or coroutines to async/await or other methods.

Comment: I think this can help you https://medium.com/@szholdiyarov/concurrent-jobs-on-android-using-promises-3fda27b3e776

Comment: If you are using Kotlin check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719864/kotlin-coroutines-how-to-block-to-await-join-all-jobs

Answer (score 1):

in your response success you need to call again get/post method.
after success you know your api call is done or else it throw error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@shkschneider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603270/shkschneider)

> Your question is broad. You could use RxJava to zip, or coroutines to async/await or other methods.

Ended up with usage of `.zip`

```
Single.zip(observables) { args -> args }
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe({ ...Success }, { ...Failure })
```